# How to return FileSystemResource or json with Spring RestController?

Tags: java, json, spring, api, rest

I have a method to download a zip file and at the moment I use FileSystemResource to do it. The problem is with a extension controller, I ccheck if a file is really zip file and I throw an exception if isn't so.
This exception create a Json object with error details and return it.
The problem is the type of Rest api because now I have :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/zipDownload", produces="application/zip", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public FileSystemResource getZip(@RequestParam(value="filePath", required=true) String filePath ) throws FileExtensionException{
    return file.getZipFile(filePath);
}
```

and services:

```
public FileSystemResource getZipFile(String fileName) throws FileExtensionException {
    String ext=FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);
    if (!ext.equals("zip"))
        throw new FileExtensionException(ext + " and not zip");
    return new FileSystemResource(new File(fileName));
}
```

the exception

```
public class FileExtensionException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public FileExtensionException(String message){
        super("The selected file has a different extension:" + message);
    }
}
```

and exception controller

```
@ControllerAdvice 
public class ErrorController {

    /**
     * 
     * @param e: exception thrown
     * @return ErroreResponse
     */
     @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public @ResponseBody ErrorResponse errorHandler(Exception e){   
        //Make the exception by buildErrorResponse
        return ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
    }
}
```

The problem another exception launched by Spring that override mine:

> 2015-09-21 09:09:05.197 ERROR 7500 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to invoke
>   @ExceptionHandler method: public matlab.ErrorResponse
>   matlab.ErrorController.errorHandler(java.lang.Exception)
>
> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not
>   find acceptable representation at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:173)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:101)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:185)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:362)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:60)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:138)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:74)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1183)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1020)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:116)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:60)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:91)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:109)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 2015-09-21 09:09:05.201 ERROR 7500 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter : Forwarding to error page from
>   request [/ManagmentFile/zipDownload] due to exception [The selected
>   file has a different extension:xlsx and not zip]
>
> matlab.FileExtensionException: The selected file has a different
>   extension:xlsx and not zip at
>   matlab.FileServices.getZipFile(FileServices.java:46) at
>   matlab.ws.FileManagerImpl.getZip(FileManagerImpl.java:38) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:116)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:60)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:91)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:109)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

How can I return Zip file or json message in the same method? the problem is , produces="application/zip", without this recieve the correct error json but it doesn't download the file, otherwise vice versa
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

You can keep your `getZip` from your controller as is and just change your `@ExceptionHandler` this way :

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public @ResponseBody ErrorResponse errorHandler(Exception e, HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.setAttribute(HandlerMapping.PRODUCIBLE_MEDIA_TYPES_ATTRIBUTE, Collections.singleton(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    return ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
}
```

Here I just modify the request and reset the `PRODUCIBLE_MEDIA_TYPES_ATTRIBUTE` parameter to tell explicitly to Spring what representation I want to use.

Comment: do you have a example of this?

Comment: Here is probably what you want to achieve, I just edited my answer so you can just copy and paste this to your `ErrorController`. Tell me if it works for you !

Comment: I have removed @ResponseStatus because it is in my ErrorResponse and  it seems to work. You save me a lot of time. Thanks